# ansible の他に、AWS EC2 のプロビジョニングに適したツールはありますか？

Tags: aws, ansible, provisioning

ansible を勉強し始めてから２週間以上経つのですが
何一つやりたいことができていなくて困っています

AWS環境に対してプロビジョニングする場合に
ホスト内の操作と外部からAWSコマンドで設定することが混在するため
ansible はあまり適したツールではないように思います

やりたいことは普段停止しているインスタンスがあれば起動して
インスタンス内の設定ファイルを変更してデーモン再起動
レシピを実行した後停止する

という単純な内容なのですが
インスタンスの起動停止はインスタンス内ではなくローカル側のAWSコマンドで行う必要があるため
リモート内の作業レシピとうまく混在させることができません

このようなAWS環境のプロビジョニングに適切なツール等があれば紹介していただけるとありがたいです

Answer (score 2):

私は[AWS Systems Manager オートメーション](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html)を使っています。

- [aws:changeInstanceState](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html#automation-action-changestate)で指定したインスタンスの起動し、起動完了を待つことができます
- [aws:runCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html#automation-action-runcommand)で指定したインスタンスに対して、SSMドキュメントを実行できます

  - aws:runCommandでは`AWS-RunShellScript`ドキュメントを指定することで、シェルスクリプトを実行できます

Comment: 早速使ってみます！